# Keras classification improvement

Tags: classification, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to find a dog in a picture. I have trained my model with 2 classes. 0-dog, 1-nondog. 9500 for training and 3000for validation each. My model:

```
#model dog/nondog categorical more features to extract
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, input_shape=(3, image_w, image_h)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(16))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adadelta',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I have trained it to 90%+ accuracy.
`Accuracy vs Val_Accuracy:` https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw5G7.jpg
`Loss vs Val_Loss:` [http://imgur.com/a/M6c1M](https://imgur.com/a/M6c1M)

My approach to this was to classify dogs from nondogs, then go through an image in steps of 50pixels(can be changed), so if the "box" is a dog it returns me a location of the box, then when scan is complete through a whole image, boxes are ploted. Here is an example of the output image (red box is box that got classified as dog).
Example output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoAck.jpg

The problem Im having is that when I scan through a "real" image with different object etc, It never finds the dog itself. It completely misses the dog.
Example output2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QLEp.jpg

Can anyone explain why is this happening? Did I approach this problem incorrectly? What changes can/if any I do? Any help is apprceated! 
Thank you!

Full code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Jan 26 16:21:36 2017

@author: PoLL
"""

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
import PIL
from PIL import Image
#draw rect
import matplotlib.patches as patches

#########################################################################################################
#VALUES
# dimensions of images.
image_w, image_h = 150,150
training_direct = 'data1/train'
validation_direct = 'data1/validation'
training_samples = 19000 #8500dogs 8500nondogs
validation_samples = 6000 #3000dogs 3000nondogs
epochs = 30
#########################################################################################################
#MODELS


#model dog/nondog categorical more features to extract
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, input_shape=(3, image_w, image_h)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(16))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adadelta',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

############################################################################################

#Configuration of training data augmentation
training_data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

# rescaling as preprocessing for better results
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
############################################################################################
#PREPARE TRAINING DATA
T_generator = training_data_generator.flow_from_directory(
        training_direct, #data1/train
        target_size=(image_w, image_h),  #RESIZE to 150/150
        batch_size=64,
        class_mode='categorical')  #label categorical/binary

#PREPARE VALIDATION DATA
V_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_direct,  #data1/validation
        target_size=(image_w, image_h), #RESIZE 150/150
        batch_size=64,
        class_mode='categorical')  #label categorical/binary


#START model.fit
history =model.fit_generator(
        T_generator, #train data
        samples_per_epoch=training_samples, #parameters
        nb_epoch=epochs,
        validation_data=V_generator,  #validation data
        nb_val_samples=validation_samples)


#check labels 0=dog 1=nondog
labels = (T_generator.class_indices)
print(labels)




############################################################################################
##### WINDOW BOX  TO GO THROUGH THIS IMAGE
image=load_img('finddog/findadog2.jpg')
image= np.array(image).reshape((600,1050,3))
plt.imshow(image)
print(image.shape)


############################################################################################
############################################################################################
#OBJECT IS HERE

#object x,y,w,h,
object0 =  (140, 140, 150,150)
object1 =  (340, 340, 150,150)
#object2 = (130,130,150,150)
objloc  = []
objloc.append(object0)
objloc.append(object1)
#objloc.append(object2)


#SLIDING WINDOW
def find_a_dog(image, step=50, window_sizes=[150]):
    boxCATDOG = 0  
    locations = []
    for win_size in window_sizes:
        #top =y, left =x
        for Y in range(0, image.shape[0] - win_size + 1, step):
            for X in range(0, image.shape[1] - win_size + 1, step):
                # compute the (top, left, bottom, right) of the bounding box
                box = (Y, X, Y + win_size, X + win_size)
                # crop
                cropped_img = image[box[0]:box[2], box[1]:box[3]]
                #reshape cropped image by window             
                cropped_img = np.array(cropped_img).reshape((1,3,150,150))

                #classify it
                boxCATDOG = predict_function(cropped_img)              
                if boxCATDOG ==0:
                 #   print('box classified as dog') 
                    #save location of it                 
                    locations.append(box)

                    print("found dog")


        return locations                                 



############################################################################################                   
#FUNCTIONS   #
def predict_function(x):
    result = model.predict_classes(x)
    if result==1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0   
#SHOW CROPPED IMAGE
def show_image(im):
   plt.imshow(im.reshape((150,150,3)))
#SHOW INPUT IMAGE
def show_ori_image(im):
   plt.imshow(im.reshape((600,1050,3)))


#DRAW WHERE OBJECT IS   
def draw_obj_loc(image,objectloc):
    fix,ax = plt.subplots(1)
    ax.imshow(image)
    for l in objloc:
        rectG = patches.Rectangle((l[0],l[1]),l[2],l[3],linewidth=1,edgecolor='G',facecolor='none')
        ax.add_patch(rectG)
    print len(objectloc)

#DRAW BOXES FROM LOCATIONS
def draw_boxes(image, locations):
    fix,ax = plt.subplots(1)
    ax.imshow(image)       
    for l in locations:
        print l
        rectR = patches.Rectangle((l[1],l[0]),150,150,linewidth=1,edgecolor='R',facecolor='none')
        ax.add_patch(rectR)
    print len(locations)

#DRAW GREEN AND RED
def draw_both(image, locations,objectloc):
    fix,ax = plt.subplots(1)
    ax.imshow(image)
    for l in objloc:
        rectG = patches.Rectangle((l[0],l[1]),l[2],l[3],linewidth=1,edgecolor='G',facecolor='none')
        ax.add_patch(rectG)
    for l in locations:
        print l
        rectR = patches.Rectangle((l[1],l[0]),150,150,linewidth=1,edgecolor='R',facecolor='none')
        ax.add_patch(rectR)

#CHECK OVERLAPPING GREEN RED
def check_overlapping(image,locations,objloc):   

    for ol in objloc:
        objX = (ol[0])
        objY = (ol[1])
        objW = (ol[2])
        objH = (ol[3])

        for ok in locations:
            X=(ok[0])
            Y=(ok[1])
   # for l in locations:
        #  if (objX+objW<X or X+150<objX or objY+objH<Y or Y+150<objY):
            if (objX+objW<X or X+150<objX or objY+objH<Y or Y+150<objY):
                # Intersection = Empty
                       #no overlapping, false positive
                       print('THERES NO OVERLAPPING :',objloc.index(ol))
                        #                                              
            else:
                        #Intersection = Not Empty
                        print('THERE IS OVERLAPPING WITH OBJECT: ',objloc.index(ol), 'WITH BOX NUMBER: ',locations.index(ok))

############################################################################################       

#get locations from image
locations = find_a_dog(image)
#show where windowslide classifed as positive
draw_boxes(image,locations)
```

Comment: What happens when you increase the threshold for prediction? Using `if boxCATDOG == 0:` after prediction is a bit strong. Try changing it to something like `if boxCATDOG <= 0.25:` and see if the dogs are found.

Comment: @oscfri Hi, thank you for reply! I tried a model with binary labels aswell. Problem is that when I predict in both cases answers are always 0 or 1. Its never a decimal number. even when I did model.predict_proba is not  decimal number.

Comment: You need to create an input image pyramid of varying scales to capture the scale variation of the object. Your whole implementation is kind of brute force right now. Once you get this working, you should use a fully convolutional network to classify different grids of the image at the same time.